# How do i transform a string into an openssl_encrypt string?

Tags: php, vb.net

i have to translate a string into openssl encrypt AES-256.

The agency gave me a code snippet how they translate the code in VB.net

```
Dim iv As Byte() = {&HDB, &H84, &H95, &HBD, &HDA, &HD5, &HD3, &HF8, &HCE, &H81, &H9C, &HA5, &HB3, &H8B, &H24, &H54} (16 Character)
```

the password is already a hex-code "4093f94891...."

i want to use the following function

```
openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, $option, $iv);
$string = "my string"
$encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC"
$key = "4093f94891...."
$option = 0
$iv = ???
```

How do i translate the iv as byte() ?

1. Dim iv As Byte() = {&HDB, &H84, &H95, &HBD, &HDA, &HD5, &HD3, &HF8,
   &HCE, &H81, &H9C, &HA5, &HB3, &H8B, &H24, &H54} (16 Character) in
   PHP ?

Comment: I think `pack()` might be what to are looking for. `$iv = pack('H*',"DB8495BDDAD5D3F8CE819CA5B38B2454");`

Comment: hey riggsfolly, i try pack() and replace "DB8495BDDAD5D3F8CE819CA5B38B2454" with my $key .. but i do not get the same result as the agency

Comment: Ok, so what result do you get from the agency?

Comment: This is the result from the agency: 7DAusJumI74hDuCSI1ZD9Jwhb3XmUraPQpKADutBOlXRRDM91mkqbtX8cqQ8COXA8ifiOGiAvUK8wys9OA2iBxfj2sYhRA9ZB8fY3pIxwX1fsMCNsvtM+SUim6UHhWJCbxVIuUXOy5FQGFsqOu+ElHRj2ef0CtUtKyE4T4j8NqKmT1yqsxRjNgOLWT/JeVwOS3WwfCVmmatbs8UPsYqX7C15n4I/WzkEmJGmGB2NDthB1BbTvYVRD/jjQdZUkjrGt3mDom6x6kNb3jF/P1UHbUGgf9+kGhSRQy0tySVS7ixZsZtve7S8vokCq33dQehFk03hRnYFOX0SE04dONTvs9q6cvtyFew8wmo3y6YkeWws1qnYUk3r4kdzj/9GE4hge1gTZTRmodRQZh4PELY6hA==

Comment: This is my result: 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

Comment: NO, I ment what is the contents of `iv` ... the value we are trying to imitate

Comment: I understand, i wrote them a couple of times which value is behind but they only send me the information to compile the string.. they not cooperative :(